# how to make child element visible and invisible maintaining right parent-child relationship

Tags: jquery, html, css, parent-child

I've made a div which have child and those children have child too. I want when user click on the "Show" button, child elements will be appeared. At the same time "Hide" button will be set instead of "Show" button. If user click on the "Hide" button, opposite event will be happened. I can put some jQuery code successfully. But the problem is, when anyone click on the "Show" button, it'll show every child elements and child's child elements. But, I want that if user click on the "Show" button on "A" element, it'll open only A's child, if they click on the "Show" button on the A's child, only then A's child's child should be appeared.

Here is my working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/PcNu2/

```
<div class="box">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="row">
                <p class="left">A</p>
                <a href="#" class="right showButton">Show</a>
                <a href="#" class="right hideButton">Hide</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="child">
                <li>
                    <div class="row">
                        <p class="left">- A's Child 1</p>
                        <a href="#" class="right showButton">Show</a>
                        <a href="#" class="right hideButton">Hide</a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="child child2">
                        <li>
                            <div class="row">
                                <p class="left">- A's Child 1's child 1</p>
                            </div> 
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="row">
                                <p class="left">- A's Child 1's child 2</p>
                            </div> 
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="row">
                        <p class="left">- A's Child 2</p>
                        <a href="#" class="right showButton">Show</a>
                        <a href="#" class="right hideButton">Hide</a>
                    </div>
                    <ul class="child child2">
                        <li>
                            <div class="row">
                                <p class="left">- A's Child 2's child 1</p>
                            </div> 
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="row">
                                <p class="left">- A's Child 2's child 2</p>
                            </div> 
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="row">
                <p class="left">B</p>
                <a href="#" class="right showButton">Show</a>
                <a href="#" class="right hideButton">Hide</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="child">
                <li>
                    <div class="row">
                        <p class="left">- B's Child 1</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use only one button in each level and update accordingly:
http://jsfiddle.net/sbritton/J6c3z/

```
<div class="box">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="row">
                <p class="left">A</p>
                <a href="#" class="right showButton">Show</a>                
            </div>
            <ul class="child">
                <li>
                    <div class="row">
                        <p class="left">- A's Child 1</p>
                        <a href="#" class="right showButton">Show</a>                        
                    </div>
                    <ul class="child child2">
                        <li>
                            <div class="row">
                                <p class="left">- A's Child 1's child 1</p>
                            </div> 
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="row">
                                <p class="left">- A's Child 1's child 2</p>
                            </div> 
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="row">
                        <p class="left">- A's Child 2</p>
                        <a href="#" class="right showButton">Show</a>                        
                    </div>
                    <ul class="child child2">
                        <li>
                            <div class="row">
                                <p class="left">- A's Child 2's child 1</p>
                            </div> 
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="row">
                                <p class="left">- A's Child 2's child 2</p>
                            </div> 
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="row">
                <p class="left">B</p>
                <a href="#" class="right showButton">Show</a>                
            </div>
            <ul class="child">
                <li>
                    <div class="row">
                        <p class="left">- B's Child 1</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>


$(".box").on('click','.showButton', function(){
  $(this).parent().next("ul.child").show();
  $(this).removeClass('showButton').addClass('hideButton').text('Hide');

});

$(".box").on('click','.hideButton', function(){  
  $(this).closest('li').find(".child").hide();
  $(this).closest('li').find('.hideButton').removeClass('hideButton').addClass('showButton').text('Show');
});
```

Comment: Also, if you go with this approach, don't forget to remove the following CSS:
.hideButton {
    display: none;
}

Comment: Thanks! But, I've seen another issue on it. If It's expanded any child's child, and at that time if anyone click on the "Hide" button on the main parent("A") li and after that again click on the "Show" button on the "A" li, it expand previous child's child element too as it was open before hiding from the main parent. So, is it possible when user click hide button on the parent div, it'll hide child's child element too if any of those are open?

Comment: OK, take another look - that should do it
[FIDDLE] (http://jsfiddle.net/sbritton/J6c3z/1/)